# HQL search in all properties

Tags: java, hql

I'm using HQL,

I want to find customers who have any property that contains 'mc',

Is there any other query shorter than this?

```
  @Query("select c from Customer c where c.name like %:mc%"
        + " or c.mail like %:mc%"
        + " or c.adress like %:mc%"
        + " or c.tel like %:mc%"
        + " or c.cin like %:mc%")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Spring JPA to achieve this result instead. I believe it will be cleaner.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByName(String name);
    List<Customer> findByMail(String mail);
    List<Customer> findbyTel(String tel);
    List<Customer> findByCin(String cin);
}

@Service
public CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepo;

    public List<Customer> searchCustomers(String keyword){

        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

        customers.addAll(customerRepo.findByName(keyword));
        customers.addAll(customerRepo.findByMail(keyword));
        customers.addAll(customerRepo.findbyTel(keyword));
        customers.addAll(customerRepo.findByCin(keyword));

        return customers;
    }
}
```

If any of these fields are unique then you should change the List return type to simply Customer and change the corresponding add method from addAll(Collection) to add(Object);

Comment: thanks for the response, but in my case I work with HQL and want to find a shorter query